# ZXing : CoreScr files are missing?

Tags: ios, zxing

While integrating ZXing library in IOS, I am facing a strange error in Library. Compiler  says that CoreScr folder doesn't contain any files.

I check out the code using SmartSVN 6. In that ScanTest Sample application is also throwing same error.
Any help on this appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a typo in your project. There is no "CoreScr" folder anywhere. There is a "cpp/core/src" folder that is relevant. Make sure you've entered the right paths.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: I've already voted to close :)